# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error on Google Cloud Run Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had a service running on Google Cloud Run and it was working perfectly fine. But recently I'm unable to access the service. When I try to access the service via the URL: https://mekanik-backend-7vdtkyiedq-as.a.run.app/

I get the following error: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

What I see on screen:
[image]

Expected:

[image]

Surprisingly, it's not working on my network but works on my friends network.

Comment: Your Cloud Run service is using Django. Django is failing/crashing/misconfigured and is returning a 404 NOT FOUND error.

Comment: @JohnHanley it's working on other devices

Comment: You have not included those details in your question. I clicked your URL, it is reporting an error.

Comment: I've added updated the question

Comment: There several possibilities: 1) The DNS settings on your desktop are wrong. 2) The browser has cached a setting from your site. Try a different browser. 3) Use the command-line tool `curl -I -v URL` to help debug connecting to your service.